# How to ensure my code is ansi C, no C++ involved. Could compiler like gcc can be set to prompt error when meeting feature in C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I programmed C++ for a while.
Now I want to program a ANSI C program, don't want any "C++ only" feature in the code.
I'm using cygwin 64 bit with gcc installed.
Are there any settings to let gcc prompt compiler error if encounter C++ features? E.g. the stl.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Compile using a C (and not C++) compiler, in first place.

Comment: In addition, GCC and clang support the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c89 -ansi -pedantic -pedantic-errors` flags.

Comment: Depending on your compiler flags, simply having a .c extension for the source file may be enough.

Comment: @H2CO3, what is the proper C compiler? Is gcc the candidate?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ANSI C"? That term usually refers to the (officially obsolete) 1989/1990 version of the language, but [ANSI itself](http://ansi.org/) currently recognizes only the 2011 standard.

Comment: @H2CO3: `-std=c89`, `-std=c90`, and `-ansi` are synonymous; you have redundant options.

Comment: @KeithThompson, thanks, I didn't realize the question is so useful. Actually, I don't know, I will use C90. Should the C99 and later version be able to parse the code based on C90?

Comment: Each standard is based on the previous one. With a few exceptions, valid C90 code is also valid C99 code, and valid C99 code is also valid C11 code. The standard committee is reasonably careful to avoid breaking old code. Drafts of the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) are available; each has a foreword that summarizes the changes from the previous edition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is taken from the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Standards.html#Standards):

> The original ANSI C standard (X3.159-1989) was ratified in 1989 and
>   published in 1990. This standard was ratified as an ISO standard
>   (ISO/IEC 9899:1990) later in 1990. There were no technical differences
>   between these publications, although the sections of the ANSI standard
>   were renumbered and became clauses in the ISO standard. This standard,
>   in both its forms, is commonly known as C89, or occasionally as C90,
>   from the dates of ratification. The ANSI standard, but not the ISO
>   standard, also came with a Rationale document. To select this standard
>   in GCC, use one of the options -ansi, -std=c90 or -std=iso9899:1990;
>   to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should
>   also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be
>   errors rather than warnings).

So, compile using the following flags:

```
gcc myfile.c -ansi -pedantic-errors
```

Notice that -ansi and -std=c90 are synonyms. For the full list of options, refer to [Options Controlling C Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

Comment: Be sure the source file name has a `.c` suffix, not `.cpp` or even `.C`.

Comment: Or be explicit and use `-x c`